# Need inner and outer join in one function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have one table that holds a record for each customer (main table). I then have a table with additional detail for some customers. The additional detail table sometimes has no records for a record in the main table. Sometimes the detail table has multiple records for a record in the main table & if this is the case I need the most recent record (hence the max subselect).

The trouble is my function only returns values for the few records in the detail table. If I comment out the portion of the function that looks at the detail table and just return the `STAT3` value it seems to work. How do I make the second select statment below only apply if there is a result for that query?

```
create or replace FUNCTION           "F_RETURN_STAT" (
N_UNIQUE IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
V_STAT3 varchar2(20);
V_STAT varchar2(20);
V_STAT2 varchar2(20);
D_ACTDATE date;
D_STARTDATE date;

BEGIN
select expire into D_ACTDATE
from main_table a
where a.uniquefield = N_UNIQUE;
IF 
D_ACTDATE > SYSDATE
or 
D_ACTDATE is null
then
V_STAT :='TRUE';
else 
v_STAT :='FALSE';
end if;


select b.startdate into D_STARTDATE
from main_table a, detail_table b
where a.uniquefield= b.main_table_id(+) and
b.main_table_id = N_UNIQUE and
b.uniquefield in 
  (select max(c.uniquefield) from detail_table c  group by main_table_id);
if 
D_STARTDATE is not null
 then
V_STAT2 :='FALSE';
  end if;

    if 
 V_STAT2 ='FALSE'
        then
        V_STAT3 :='FALSE';
        ELSE
 V_STAT3 := V_STAT;
        end if ;
RETURN(V_STAT3);
end;
```

Comment: What's the point of doing the outer join if the only field you're selecting will be null either way? Even if you made this work, `D_START_DATE` would still be null.

Comment: it won't always be null. the function returns "FALSE" if it isn't null. if it is null it returns the value of the first query and first if statment. Sorry if you had to re-read this.i have updated this comment numerous times

Comment: My point is that the query that you're asking about will return `null` into `D_STARTDATE` if there is no row in `detail_table` whether you use an inner or outer join in the query. Or at least it would if you were using an explicit cursor. As it is, you could change the join to an inner join and catch the `NO_ROW_FOUND` error instead of trying to make the outer join work.

Comment: ahh ok.. i tried adding something to effect of if STAT2 is null but that didn't work. so I guess you have to explicitly add something to produce the null otherwise it only looks at records that have have a matching record in the detail table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this version of your function will solve your problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_return_stat(n_unique IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   v_stat3     VARCHAR2(20);
   v_stat      VARCHAR2(20);
   v_stat2     VARCHAR2(20);
   d_actdate   DATE;
   d_startdate DATE;
BEGIN
   --First Query
   SELECT expire
   INTO   d_actdate
   FROM   main_table a
   WHERE  a.uniquefield = n_unique;

   IF d_actdate > SYSDATE OR d_actdate IS NULL THEN
      v_stat   := 'TRUE';
   ELSE
      v_stat   := 'FALSE';
   END IF;

   BEGIN
      --Second Query
      SELECT b.startdate
      INTO   d_startdate
      FROM   detail_table b
      WHERE  b.main_table_id = n_unique
         AND b.uniquefield IN (SELECT   MAX(c.uniquefield)
                               FROM     detail_table c
                               GROUP BY main_table_id);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         d_startdate   := NULL;
   END;

   IF d_startdate IS NOT NULL THEN
      v_stat2   := 'FALSE';
   END IF;

   IF v_stat2 = 'FALSE' THEN
      v_stat3   := 'FALSE';
   ELSE
      v_stat3   := v_stat;
   END IF;

   RETURN (v_stat3);
END;
```

In your version of the second query, your join (`a.uniquefield= b.main_table_id`) and your filter (`b.main_table_id = N_UNIQUE`) are equivalent, so `main_table a` can be removed altogether. The only reason to leave it in is to make sure that your query always returns a row. If you use exception handling to catch the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception, that need goes away and you can simplify your query to just select from `detail_table b`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there could be a more efficient way however this might do the job:

```
 SELECT b.startdate
 INTO   d_startdate
 FROM   detail_table b
 WHERE  b.main_table_id = n_unique
 and
 (b.uniquefield in 
  (select max(c.uniquefield) from detail_table c  group by main_table_id)
    or b.uniquefield is null);
```

Comment: hmmm this gives a missing right parenthesis error. and i think wont work because the query doesn't return a null if there is no match in the main table... it only returns a result if there is a record in the detail table. it looks like an outer join but i think the max subquery forces an inner join. thanks for looking at this btw